# AppleScript returns text with strange characters

Tags: text, applescript, character

I have a script to return parts of a text file, but I notice it sometimes returns characters that are not visible when viewing the text file directly. For example, the word:

```
breeders
```

becomes

```
breedÂ¬â rs
```

I tried adding "as Unicode text" to my text return, but that isn't working. Thoughts? Here's my script:

```
set some_file to "[...]Words.txt" as alias
set the_text to read some_file as string
set the text item delimiters of AppleScript to ", "
set the_lines to (every text item of the_text)
return some item of the_lines as Unicode text
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like `ruby -KU -e '"breeders".chars{|c|puts c.unpack("U*")[0].to_s(16)}'` or searching for the characters that aren't displayed correctly in Character Viewer?

`read` will jumble up non-ASCII characters unless you add `as «class utf8»`:

```
do shell script "echo ä > /tmp/test.txt"
read POSIX file "/tmp/test.txt" as «class utf8»
```

`as text`, `as string`, and `as Unicode text` have been equivalent [since 10.5](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/AppleScript/RN-AppleScript/RN-10_5/RN-10_5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000982-CH105-SW1).

Comment: I can use PlainClip to cut, "remove invisible control characters" from the clipboard, and paste. But I was hoping not to have to do that every so often. Not sure how to do pbpaste or the shell script. Can you put your code in context? If I replace "as string" with "as «class utf8»", the formatting improves to breedÂers, but it's still not perfect.

Comment: Actually, pbpaste doesn't work that well with non-ASCII characters either, so I replaced it with a Ruby command. The original text file probably contains some unintended characters in any case.

Comment: Can you put the ruby command in the context of my AppleScript code? I don't know that language at all. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry. It can be run by just pasting it in Terminal. It prints the code points of characters; if some are `80` or larger (not ASCII) or `1F` or lower (ASCII control characters), you can search for them in Character Viewer to see what characters they are.

Comment: But I want this as an AppleScript...so can I just use 'do shell code "what you pasted above"'?

Comment: It was just meant as a way to check if parts of the input text file contain some unexpected characters. If you can't modify the text file, for example `do shell script "sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' Words.txt"` would remove everything except printable ASCII characters.

Comment: Great, so how do I save the output of sed to some_file, as in my script above?

Comment: You can redirect it with `do shell script "sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' Words.txt" > some_file.txt`.

Comment: How would I save the output to a variable instead of creating a new file? I tried replacing the first line of my script with `do shell script "sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' Words.txt" > some_file` but that errored.

Comment: `set some_file to do shell script "sed 's/[^[:print:]]//g' Words.txt"`.